# Predicates vs if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, lambda, java-8, predicate

I have seen in some projects that people use `Predicate`s instead of pure if statements, as illustrated with a simple example below:

```
    int i = 5;
    // Option 1
    if (i == 5) {
        // Do something
        System.out.println("if statement");
    }

    // Option 2
    Predicate<Integer> predicate = integer -> integer == 5;
    if (predicate.test(i)) {
        // Do something
        System.out.println("predicate");
    }
```

What's the point of preferring `Predicate`s over if statements?

Comment: This is useful for when you want to re-use the predicate. To give an example: what if you want to apply a specific filter to different `List`s? What if you want to change that specific filter? Using predicates is a great way to prevent yourself from having to change code in 100's of places down the line.

Comment: For the example that you give, a predicate is completely unnecessary and only makes things more complicated for no good reason.

Comment: Technically you are using if statement for both usage. Predicate is a functional interface to generate variant conditions, with this you can test these variant conditions in your logic.

Comment: Voting to re-open. The scope of this question is not too broad, and it has attracted some decent quality answers so far.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For the **exact** example that you provided, using a Predicate is a big over-kill. The compiler and then the runtime will create:

> 1. a method (de-sugared predicate)
> 2. a .class that will implement java.util.Predicate
> 3. an instance of the class created at 2

all this versus a simple if statement.

*And all this for a stateless Predicate*. If your predicate is statefull, like:

```
 Predicate<Integer> p = (Integer j) -> this.isJGood(j); // you are capturing "this"
```

then every time you will use this Predicate, a new instance will be created (at least under the current JVM).

The only viable option IMO to create such a Predicate is, of course, to re-use it in multiple places (like passing as arguments to methods).

Answer (score 22):

Using a predicate makes your code more flexible.

Instead of writing a condition that always checks if `i == 5`, you can write a condition that evaluates a `Predicate`, which allows you to pass different `Predicate`s implementing different conditions.

For example, the `Predicate` can be passed as an argument to a method :

```
public void someMethod (Predicate<Integer> predicate) {
    if(predicate.test(i)) {
        // do something
        System.out.println("predicate");
    }
    ...
}
```

This is how the `filter` method of `Stream` works.

Comment: Nevertheless, if you don't need that flexibility, it stands to reason that you shouldn't use `Predicate<>`. Sure, it's a great tool where appropriate, but it complicates code if used along the lines of the OP's example.

Comment: @cmaster That's certainly true.

Answer (score 0):

Using if statements is the best (read: most performant) way to check binary conditions.

The switch statement may be faster for more complex situations.

A `Predicate` are a special form of `Function`. In fact the java language architect work on a way to allow generic primitive types. This will make `Predicate<T>` roughly equivalent to `Function<T, boolean>` (modulo the test vs apply method name).

If a function (resp. method) takes one or more functions as argument(s), we call it *higher-order function*. We say that we are passing *behaviour* to a function. This allows us to create powerful APIs.

```
String result = Match(arg).of(
        Case(isIn("-h", "--help"),    help()),
        Case(isIn("-v", "--version"), version()),
        Case($(),                     cmd -> "unknown command: " + cmd)
);
```

This example is taken from [Javaslang](http://javaslang.io), a library for object-functional programming in Java 8+.

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of Javaslang.

Answer (score 0):

Thi is an old question, but I'll give it a try, since I am battling with it myself...

In my attempt to excuse my own usage of predicates I have made a self-rule.

I believe Predicates are useful where the "logic point"  - is **NOT** the: **leaf | corner | the end**  - of a: **graph | tree | straight line**, which would make the logic point effectively a "logic joint".

By it being a joint (aka node) it has a state, a re-usable and mutable state, that serves as a means towards an end.

In a stream, where the data is supposed to traverse a path, predicates are useful since they grant a degree of access while keeping the integrity of the stream, this is why the best predicates IMO are only method references minimizing side effects.

Even though the most common form of Predicate is newObject.equal(old), which is in itself a BiPredicate, but CAN be used with a single Predicate with side effect `lambda -> lambda.equal(localCache)` (so this may be an exception to the Only Method References rule).

IF, the logic serves as the output/exit point towards a different architectural design, or component, or a code that is not written by you, or even if it is written by you, one that differs on its functionality, then an if-else is my way to go.

Another benefit of predicates in the case of reactive programming is that multiple subscribers can make use of the same defined logic gate.

But if the end point of a publisher will be a single lone subscriber (which would be a case similar to your example if I'm reaching), then the logic is better done with an if-else.